# VBA nested if inquiry

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to write write a nested if statement in VBA. In cobol, I would typically use the evaluate clause. But what do I use in VBA so as to avoid a long loop.

Example.

```
if cmbfield = "green" then
 me.frame1.enable = true
else
 me.frame2.enable = false
 me.frame3.enable = false
end if
if cmbfield = "red" then
 me.frame2.enable = true
else
 me.frame1.enable = false
 me.frame3.enable = false
end if
if cmbfield = "white" then
 me.frame3.enable = true
else
 me.frame1.enable = false
 me.frame2.enable = false
end if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it this way:

```
Me.frame1.enabled = (cmbfield = "green")
Me.frame2.enabled = (cmbfield = "red")
Me.frame3.enabled = (cmbfield = "white")
```

Answer (score 3):

In the example you gave I'd use a switch command:

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php

```
Select Case test_expression

   Case condition_1
      result_1

   Case condition_2
      result_2

   ...

   Case condition_n
      result_n

   Case Else
      result_else

End Select
```

You could also do if ... elseif ... end if

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php

```
If condition_1 Then
   result_1

ElseIf condition_2 Then
  result_2

...

ElseIf condition_n Then
   result_n

Else
   result_else

End If
```

Comment: It appears that [COBOL's Evaluate](http://www.fluffycat.com/COBOL/Evaluate/) is equivalent to a select case. Nice answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the select case syntax. Will incorporate that in future jobs.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim isGreen as Boolean, isRed as Boolean, isWhite as Boolean
isGreen = (cmbfield = "green")
isRed = (cmbfield = "red")
isWhite = (cmbfield = "white")

me.frame1.enabled = isGreen
me.frame2.enabled = isRed
me.frame3.enabled = isWhite
```

This is a shorter way to write the same code. Should work modulo syntax; hope this helps.